# Сообщение после отправки формы

Tags: python, django

Нужно сделать чтобы после отправки html формы, под формой выводилось сообщение об успешной отправке формы

Answer (score 1):

Это работает на PHP 100% , должно и на питоне заработать.

```
$data = $_POST;    
$errors = array();   
if(isset($data['Имя кнопки'])) //Имя кнопки писать name="do_knopka" 
{
   //Сведения об ошибке - $errors = 'bla bla'
   if(empty($errors)){
//Если ошибок не найдено
$data = 'Успех!';   
}
   }
//Выводишь $data там где должно выводится сообщение об успехе
```